# How to open .docx files with Web View in Windows Phone App 8/8.1 without default MS-OFFICE

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

1. Is there any option to open word file in Windows Phone with web view ?
2. I get byte array data from specified API, and I want to show it on web view in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No
2. You are out of luck

There are two way you can handle the DOCX files. You create a file and use `Launcher.LaunchFileAsync` to let the system open it in the default app (MS Office installed on Windows Phone). Or you can try to find a third party library that can display DOCX files.

Comment: 1)Thank you very much @Igor Kulman, But Client requirement is, that 'Response'  must not be Editable & Savable. I Launch the file with Launcher.LaunchFileAsync and it open in dafault app (MS Office) and it have edit and save option.  We don't want this. We must show it on Web View. Thank again for your valuable replay but is there any option to do it or any third party tool ???

Comment: 2) Is there any way to provide read only access to that docx file when it open in Default (MS Office) App. For security purpose it should not be editable and savable.

Comment: Then a third party library is your only choice. Synfusion has a control for this but I guess you will be better of with PDF documents, there are more libraries to display those.

Comment: Ok @Igor but we don't want to use third party tools. Now how can one applied Read only and not savable permission on that .docx file which is open in Default (Ms Office). Is there any possibility to do it?

Comment: Then you are out of luck, your only choice is to implement a DOCX renderer your self, good luck with, will take you months.